# Traversing list of tuples once

Tags: python

Suppose:

```
    b = [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Can i do:

```
    c = [i for i,j in b]
    d = [j for i,j in b]
```

while traversing b once with list comprehension instead of an extended for loop?
Assume that b is a list of tuples of n items (not neccessarily 2)

Comment: You can definitely do what you wrote, but you will need to know how many items are in your tuples, and it will need to be the same number for all list items

Comment: Yes, but simpler is c, d = list(zip(*b))

Comment: @DarrylG The call to `list` is unnecessary.

Comment: @bnlhsing, right, so even simpler is c, d = zip(*b)